# Serializing an object's reference to JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 with Visual Studio 2010. A lot of my controller actions need to serialize my POCO domain objects into JSON. BTW I use nhibernate as my ORM.

I am using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer. It handles simple properties well (int, string, date, etc.), but it skips reference properties, so I have to map my object to anonymous type, and then feed this anonymous type to the JavaScriptSerializer like this:

```
Public Class Order
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Customer As User
End Class

Function Details() As ActionResult
    Dim realorder As Order = DB.Get(Of Order)(id)
    Dim flattenedorder As New With {
        .id = realorder.ID, .customerid = realorder.Customer.ID}
    Dim encoder = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    ViewData("order") = encoder.Serialize(flattenedorder)
    Return View()
End Function
```

In the above example, Order.ID is an int, but Order.Customer is a reference to another object. I have to create anonymous type where I specify .customerid = realorder.Customer.ID, so it is serialized correctly.

What I want to know is, is there an easier way? My domain objects have lots of references and I want to avoid creating anonymous type everytime I want to serialize them to JSON.

Comment: Did you tried to register a JavaScriptConverter for type User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply return the [appropriate action result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) and don't bother manually serializing:

```
Function Details() As ActionResult
    Dim realorder As Order = DB.Get(Of Order)(id)
    Dim flattenedorder As New With {
        .id = realorder.ID, .customerid = realorder.Customer.ID}
    Return Json(flattenedorder, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

As far as the references are concerned the problem stems from the fact that you are returning domain objects to the view instead of using view models. Not using view models specifically tailored to a given view is one of the most fundamental mistakes I see when people use ASP.NET MVC. So start by defining POCO objects that will represent only the portion of your domain models that is needed by the given view and then you could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to convert between your models and view models.

Comment: I don't have problem returning JSON. What I want to do is avoid creating the anonymous type. `return json` also skips properties to object.

Comment: @Endy, you don't have problems and yet you are manually instantiating a JavaScriptSerializer, using ViewData instead of strongly typed view model, return a ViewResult instead of JsonResult (which among other will take care of properly setting the Content-Type header to `application/json` which you don't do by returning a view). So I would say that you have problems. As far as the anonymous object is concerned you could replace it by a view model and let AutoMapper do the conversion for you. Also note that objects with circular references cannot be serialized to JSON.

Comment: Sorry I commented too quickly, you haven't finished your answer. I'll study AutoMapper.

Comment: it's just a code sample, I intentionally shortened it to highlight my problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Endy: You can use the Json.NET for serialize you model to Json. I usually do it like that:

- Build the DTO objects
- Use AutoMapper for mapping between my
  entities and DTO objects
- Decorating some Json.NET attributes on DTOs objects
- Coding 2 helper methods for convert
  DTOs to Json format

You can get some stuffs in my post at [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2010/08/26/customizing-the-converter-for-json-net.aspx). Hope I can help you!